# Exception while Posting to facebook

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I get exception when i try to post to facebook.I am using facebook sdk at codeplex and excption string is

> A member with the name 'Padding'
>   already exists on
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl'. Use
>   the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify
>   another name.

code is

```
 FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp(myToken.Default.appId);
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = textBoxMassPostMessage.Text;

            if (post == PostType.Link)
            {
                parameters.link = textBoxMassPostLink.Text;
                parameters.picture = postLinkPictureUrl[thumbnailMassPostPicture];
                parameters.name = textBoxArticleTitle.Text;
                parameters.caption = textBoxCaption.Text;
                parameters.description = textBoxDescription;
                //parameters.actions = new
                //{
                //    name = "View on Zombo",
                //    link = "http://www.zombo.com",
                //};
            }
            dynamic result = app.Post(id + "/feed", parameters);
```

what is the wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `parameters.description = textBoxDescription` to `textBoxDescription.Text`.

Comment: @Afnan: Because of `dynamic`. You're throwing away most compile-time  sanity checks by using it.